# structuremap entity framework 4 connection

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, entity-framework-4, structuremap

I am using the following Structuremap bootstrapping code for my entity framework 4 entities:

```
x.For<XEntities>().LifecycleIs(Lifecycles.GetLifecycle(InstanceScope.PerRequest)).Use(() => new XEntities());
```

But when I do two nearly simultaneous requests, I get the following exception:

```
EntityException:The underlying provider failed on Open.
{"The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is connecting."}
```

I am using ASP.NET MVC 2, en have the following in my Application_Start()
    EndRequest += new EventHandler(MvcApplication_EndRequest);

```
void MvcApplication_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ObjectFactory.ReleaseAndDisposeAllHttpScopedObjects();
}
```

What can I do to fix this?

[edit]
this happens on a page with several images on it. The images come from the database, served by an Controller Action, which reads the image from the database, and sends it as a file result to the browser. I think that asp.net is breaking down my objectcontext, and closing my db connection when the requests for the images come in, and the exception is thrown.

What I need now, is a correct way to manage the lifetime of the object context in the good way.

Comment: You definitely do not want to be calling anything on ObjectFactory in the EndRequest event. ObjectFactory is static, meaning it is the same object used on all of your requests. You could be calling ReleaseAndDispose on a request that is midway through processing.

Comment: What is XEntities? Is that the object that manages your database connection?

Comment: You probably don't want InstanceScope.PerRequest lifecycle, as that is the default (where request = a call to the container). I assume you mean "give me the same object throughout an HTTP request". If that is the case, look at the HTTP scoped lifecycles, as RPM1984 suggests below.

Comment: XEntities is my EF ObjectContext.

Comment: When I use x.For<XEntities>().HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped().Use(new XEntities()); I get an exception: The underlying provider failed onOpen, with InnerException: {"Invalid operation. The connection is closed."}

Answer (score 2):

Why are you assigning a delegate for EndRequest in Application_Start()?

Just hook directly into the event:

```
protected void Application_EndRequest()
{
    ObjectFactory.ReleaseAndDisposeAllHttpScopedObjects();
}
```

Also, i have never used that syntax before, this is how i do it:

```
For<XEntities>().HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped().Use<XEntities>()
```

Also, at what point do you *new up* your Data Context? Can you show some code?

Comment: I tried your approach
    x.For<XEntities>().HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped().Use<XEntities>(new XEntities());
That is how I create my data context.

I hooked the endRequest directly in the event now, and I get the following exception: The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.

Comment: @jwdehaan - where are you using the data context? in your controllers? via a Repository? can you show some code?